# ETSI EN 300 220-2 vs ERC 70-03 Limitations

Tags: regulations, sdr

I’m trying to understand discrepancies between EN 300 220 and ERC regarding the use of 865 - 868 MHz spectrum for SDR. Current [ERC 70-03](http://www.erodocdb.dk/docs/doc98/official/pdf/rec7003e.pdf), page 8, says:

> Frequency Band: h1.2 Maximum Occupied Bandwidth: Not specified (Note: DSSS and other wideband techniques other than FHSS)
>
> Frequency Band: h1.3 Maximum Occupied Bandwidth: ≤ 100 kHz, for 1 or more channels modulation bandwidth ≤ 300 kHz (Note: Narrowband/wideband modulation)

Both are 863 - 870 MHz.

While in current [EN 300 220-2 V3.1.1](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/300200_300299/30022002/03.01.01_60/en_30022002v030101p.pdf) Annex B (harmonised) no bandwidth limitations are imposed for 865 - 868 MHz spectrum, except for 100kHz FHSS and “audio & video applications limited to 300 kHz” which obviously has nothing to do with data transmission.

Also, ERC 70-03 describes LBT+AFA as the proper mitigation technique to replace duty cycle limit, while ETSI requires only "polite spectrum access", which it defines as:

> Techniques to access spectrum and mitigate interference that employ CCA

So, only CCA (LBT) is required.

The revelant questions are:

1. My understanding is that ERC is only a recommendation, while EN 300 220 is the obligatory and binding standard. Is this correct?
2. Can AFA system be considered a “wideband technique” (provided that it divides 865-868 MHz spectrum into many non-overlapping channels each wider than 100kHz)?
3. How to explain LBT/AFA discrepancy? Previous EN300-220 V2.1.1 did indeed call for LBT+AFA, while current standard seems more relaxed.